# MongoDB couldnt connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is a picture of the response it is giving me. I cannot copy cmd stuff for some reason = (

[image: http://i.imgur.com/f6KpFIZ.png]

Please let me know if you need more info. I figure it is something sort of trivial. This is so foreign to me.

MORE DETAILS:

So the command I ran now was

```
mongod --dbpath c:\users\hassan\docs\tutorial
```

ALSO TRIED

```
mongod --dbpath c:\users\hassan\docs\tutorial\data

mongod --dbpath c:\users\hassan\docs\tutorial\data\db
```

tutorial is the folder with the app.js file that I run

Comment: Can you show us the error response you get when you run the commands above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have your `\data\db` folder. Create it and everything will be ok.

**P.S.** you can copy the text by doing right click, then mark, then select text then CTRL+C.

Comment: I tried creating a \data\db folder and a \data folder and in neither did it work ;(

Comment: @user2783087 are you sure that the folder exists, because mongo clearly tells you that it is not there.

Comment: after I add it, it still doesnt

Comment: so can you show the output as a normal text after you created a folder?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/uy9Yn9s.png
k so actually now I think it works....it just...uh..it might be a problem with my node = (

Comment: Node problem is completely another question, and I have little experience with node.js

Comment: ( = ! ty
yea I think it's node. I am not totally sure though =  (